# Server with authentication, testing using mocha, setting up the initial users causes the server to timeout

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, automated-tests, mocha.js

I've built a web server with authentication. This means that when a users makes a request (other than, sign in, register and signout), the user must provide a token. It all seems to be working well and I've been working with it on the front end for around 2 weeks already without many issues. It either completes the api request if the token is valid (in the Redis store), or returns a 'unauthorised user' message.

The issue is, I've now made the decision to start testing all my server side code thoroughly using mocha.

The only way I can currently think of doing is, is as follows:

```js
const createUser = function(data) {
    return (
        chai.request(server_addr)
        .post('auth/register')
            .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .type('form')
            .send('userName=' + data.name)
            .send('email=' + data.email)
            .send('password=' + data.password)
    );
}

before((done) => {
        var users = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < num_users; i++) {
            users.push({
                name: 'user_' + i,
                email: 'test_' + i + '@gmail.com',
                password: 'password_' + i
            });
        }
        Promise.all(users.map(function(user) {
            return createUser(user);
        }))
        .then(function(r) {
            //Save the tokens some how, either in an array or otherwise.
            done();
        })
      });
```

And then store the tokens that are returned for each of the users that registers. The problem is that with the current approach, the server actually just times out, creating just 3 users. It also means that my tests have to follow an order, for instance: user_1 must sign in and then he can GET, POST etc, and because of this it means that I'm dragging around the register test to several files.

I'm sure this isn't the optimal way of doing things?

I toyed with two ideas:

1. Create a few test users that I just never sign out and therefore their tokens are valid, until the machine dies. The issue with this is that I then have to hard code these tokens somewhere, either in the code or in environment variables, it also isn't so scalable if I want to try with 100 users.
2. The second thought I had would be to turn off the authentication when the environment is in test. The issue with this is that in several places in my current controller code, I have code like this `req.user._id`, where I get the user by resolving the token in the Redis store. I don't like the idea of having to change production code in order to satisfy my tests.

Does anyone else have any alternatives to either of these approaches, currently I'm leaning towards option 1, but I look forward to hearing the responses from the community.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is the ideal way to go about this.

> Create a few test users that I just never sign out and therefore their tokens are valid, until the machine dies.

This is the way to go. More specifically:

- Create a script that [seeds the database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_seeding) with some dummy data, right before you start you tests. Ideally, you would create some users that are assumed to be already registered.
- You should of course, test a registration flow as well where you register a brand new user yourself and test if it works; Avoid using this user for your other tests. Instead, use one of the users that was added in the initial seeding.
- Create a module that exports data about the users you seeded your database with. This way you can avoid hardcoding/repeating your users and their tokens everywhere in your tests.
- When you're done with your tests, run another script that clears your database.

Ideally, run your tests against a [*test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment) database that you set up right before you begin testing and which you teardown after the tests.

Now as for your second option:

> The second thought I had would be to turn off the authentication when the environment is in test...

I would avoid this. You should test your code as it is. It also makes perfect sense that you would want to thoroughly test your authentication system.

Use `NODE_ENV=test` conditionals to alter the flow/or redirect things like:

- Where to send user registration emails.
- Calls to expensive pay-per-call external services etc.

Try not to abuse this when testing. Use it for necessity but not for convenience.

> The problem is that with the current approach, the server actually just times out, creating just 3 users

I'm guessing it's a code problem that you need to debug yourself. I've focused my answer on your testing best-practices questions instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough and detailed answer.